# Nullreference on own Custom Configsection and can't debug it

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I've created my own configsection  but i've run into a dead end. I keep on getting a `Nullreference` - exception. I've created my own configsection using the following [Guide](http://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/).

Obivously something is `Nothing` but i can't see/find what it is. Due to my gaping hole in debugging-knowledge i couldn't get any further with the debugging. Could someone point out what i'm exactly doing wrong?

App.Config (w my custom section DatabaseConnections):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="DatabaseConnections" type="TaskDatabase.Common.ConfigurationSections.ConnectionstringsConfigSection,TaskDatabase.Common"/>
  </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
<DatabaseConnections>
   <Connectionstrings>
     <add ConnName="TaskDatabase" ConnString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\...\TaskDB.accdb&quot;"></add>
   </Connectionstrings>
</DatabaseConnections>
</configuration>
```

My code for the configsection:

```
public class ConnectionstringsConfigSection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
{

    public const string DbConnectionsSectionName = "DatabaseConnections";
    private const string ConnectionStringsCollectionName = "Connectionstrings";

    [ConfigurationProperty(DbConnectionsSectionName, IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    public ConnectionStringsCollection ConnectionStrings
    {
        get
        {
            return (ConnectionStringsCollection)base[ConnectionStringsCollectionName];
        }
    }
}
```

The exception occurs at `base[ConnectionStringsCollectionName]` which returns a `nullReference`. I can't perform a `Step Into` so thats why i'm kinda stuck. Could someone say me what i'm doing wrong or how i can debug it further?

The StackTrace:

```
  bij System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.get_Item(String propertyName)
   bij TaskDatabase.Common.ConfigurationSections.ConnectionstringsConfigSection.get_ConnectionStrings() in ....
```

The ConnectionStringCollection - Class

```
public class ConnectionStringsCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public ConnectionString this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as ConnectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new ConnectionString this[string responseString]
    {
        get { return (ConnectionString)BaseGet(responseString); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(responseString) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(BaseIndexOf(BaseGet(responseString)));
            }
            BaseAdd(value);
        }
    }

    protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ConnectionString();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ConnectionString)element).NameProp;
    }
}
```

Configuration-Element:

```
//ConfigurationElement
public class ConnectionString : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("ConnName", IsRequired = true)]
    public string NameProp
    {
        get
        {
            return this["ConnName"] as string;
        }
    }
    [ConfigurationProperty("ConnString", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ConnectionstringProp
    {
        get
        {
            return this["ConnString"] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

So could someone spot the error i've made?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps you have a good reason but there is already a `<connectionStrings>` section built-in to .NET `app` and `web` config files. Create a `Settings` file for your project, and add a setting with type `Connection string` and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Just tested it. And renamed the section: `Connectionstrings` tot `MyConnStrings` but still the same issue.

Comment: Don't rename the section. I meant that you don't need a custom configuration section whatsoever as you could just use what's already available to you. After you add a setting with type `Connection string`, you can access it directly through `Properties.Settings.Default.YourSettingName`.

Comment: Using the predefined section i'm limited to just 3 properties: `name`, `connectionstring`, `provider` . But the need shall arise where i need more that those 3.

Comment: You don't *have* to use the `...` dialog for creating a connection string, you could type whatever you wanted right into the value field. Or simply use a `string`-typed property. The point was just that there's already a way to access properties programmatically and efficiently without the need to build a custom configuration section. You could load the string into a `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder` to parse out the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

You connections string contains this:

`&quot;`C:\Users\Stijn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TaskDatabase\TaskDatabase\TaskDB.accdb`&quot`;

Check the " in the beginning and at the end of the connection string.

Try removing this, maybe you copy this part from another place ;)

I hope this helps

Comment: The quotes are encoded, it shouldn't affect anything (and they are probably required for the connection string as the path to the `.accdb` file contains spaces).